# Oracle problem creating index organized table using "create as" statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

So I'm trying to create a copy of one of my tables into an index organized table, However I get an error, here is the code.

```
create table clients2 as
select *
from clients
organization index;
```

> ORA-00933:"SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: `as subquery` is the last part of [`table_properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) which follow `physical_properties` where you specify storage parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is wrong.

```
SQL> create table testiot ( object_id primary key,object_name ) 
     organization index 
     as select object_id,object_name from dba_objects 
     where object_id is not null ;

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from testiot ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    208730
```

`Organization index` must be in the definition of the table and before `as select`. On the other hand, you need to define the columns in the table and which one is the primary key for IOT.